# Why don't Python packages come with documentation, like R?

Tags: python, spyder

When you download a package to R, they always come with the documentation, which is very handy and lets you use the Help panel from RStudio offline. Why is not the same with python packages? Is it not possible to do the same from the Spyder Help panel? You need to be online to access the documentation.

Comment: Most packages and functions come with documentation and it can be accessed in a similar fashion to R, just instead of `?<function>` you use `help(<function_name>)`.

Comment: Another option is to Ctrl+click on the object of interest which will take you to the definition which will usually have a sizeable docstring.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also install `Kite`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IDE like Pycharm or so, it can navigate to the source code of the target functions or classes as long as you got them installed locally. You can read the implementation directly or the comments in the source code for usage instructions.